# App Store connect shows error "you must provide a privacy policy url" even the privacy link is provided

Tags: ios, app-store

I am submitting my app on App Store Connect\My App page and when I submit for review, it shows error on App Information:
"You must provide a Privacy Policy URL."
even I have pasted the link to the website show the privacy policy there. 
I have checked the link using

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

and they show no error.
Do you know what could be the reason and how to fix it ?
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: can you tell us that where you putted privacy policy url ?

Comment: Yes, I put as in attached image on my updated post above

Comment: click on error icon besides english(u.s). that also giving you same error ? or any other issue ?

Comment: if you have added any other language then you have to add privacy policy in that language also. please check it

Comment: You are right, @NiravKotecha. I have deleted the 2nd language and it fixed. However I have uploaded my build using Application Loader and it said upload successfully and wait for review but never reflexed on my App Store connect page. So when I submit for review on the website it shows error at Build. How could I upload to that part of the website ?

Comment: if your build have error then you have received mail from apple or itunesconnect. resolve that issue and upload again after it will reflect on website.

Comment: I have no error on build, I have used Application Loader to upload successfully and they said I just need to wait for review process. However on the website it is not showing the build I have uploaded. That is the problem, so it shows error that I haven't uploaded the build but actually I have uploaded it using Application Loader as they suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182993/discussion-between-nirav-kotecha-and-user1314404).

Comment: @user1314404 did you manage to solve this? I'm also stuck and can't submit for review.

Answer (score 23):

You need to submit the privacy policy for each localization seperately.

Answer (score 7):

Double checked all the other answers in this post and was still getting this error.

For me, it was requiring me to enter a tvOS privacy policy as well. All I had to do to remove the pending tvOS version on the left pane.

Not exactly the reason OP was getting this error, but might save someone else who comes to this stack overflow page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you have to provide privacy policy url in iTunes Connect --> your app --> App Information Tab inside.

see below screenshot for more details :

[image]

if you have added any other language then you have to add privacy policy in that language also. please check it

Comment: that is exactly what I am having now (I have described in my question) but it is still showing error.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this error when the title was simply too long, although the error didn't refer to that. On any language, the rules say 30 characters but i have found (maybe just for CJK?) that the limit can be shorter -- 29 or 28.